Is there an official source for the list of province-level divisions along with their capital acording to the People's Republic of China's government?
I have found this this article on Chinese Wikipedia that shows a table with the columns 省会 (provincial capital) and 省份 (province) (see screenshot below).

The table above contains the information that I'm looking for, but to ensure the most reliable information, I would like to read it from a public institution in the People's Republic of China (perhaps, there is a document or website under the domain www.gov.cn that list such information.)
Additional information
I found this document published on 2017 in www.gov.cn that states the following:

截至2016年底，全国共有省级行政区划单位34个（其中直辖市4个、省23个、自治区5个、特别行政区2个），地级行政区划单位334个（其中地级市293个、地区8个，自治州30个、盟3个），……

The English translation is shown below:

By the end of 2016, there were 34 provincial-level administrative division units across the country (including 4 municipalities directly under the Central Government, 23 provinces, 5 autonomous regions, and 2 special administrative regions), and 334 prefecture-level administrative division units (including 293 prefecture-level cities, 8 regions, 30 autonomous prefectures, and 3 unions).，……

So, according to the People's Republic of China, China has 34 provincial-level administrative divions, among which:

4 municipalities directly under the Central Government (in Chinese, 直辖市4个)
23 provinces (in Chinese, 省23个)
5 autonomous regions (in Chinese, 自治区5个)
2 special administrative regions (in Chinese, 特别行政区2个)

Therefore, the list of the accepted answer should have 34 entries. I suppose that every province has a capital. If that's not the case, the list should list the capital for those provinces that have it.

It seems you have your answer.  Any answer we would give would merely be a rehashing of your source. What makes you doubt your source.  What do you need to do with this information that requires a source from gov.cn?

@JamesK What makes you believe that that a Wikipedia page written by some random people on the Internet is likely to be accurate? By any reasonable standards Wikipedia isn't a source for anything. Looking for a proper source to verify that page is exactly what the OP should be, and is, doing.

@cjs wikipedia tables on government info are usually reliably sourced in my experience, if occasionally outdated.

@qwr Well, "usually reliably sourced" may satisfy you, but that's nowhere near good enough for academic use, where you need a source for those particular data, and "well other stuff I got from there seemed to be reliable" doesn't cut it. In fact, the same is true of Wikipedia itself: it expressly prohibits the use of other Wikipedia pages as sources.

@rdrg109 I believe this question was incorrectly closed (as is probably clear from my comments), but it occurs to me that if you rephrase it as just, "is this the correct list of all divisions and capitals?" (removing all your backstory about how you came to the question)  it seems to me it would be appropriate for skeptics.stackexchange.com.

You can also edit your post here to attempt to address the issues raised by the close votes, and a moderator can then look at it and re-open it if they find the problem is fixed. So you could try removing all the backstory from your question here as well, reducing it just to, "Is this is the correct list? Is there an official government source for this?"

@cjs what would make you believe that an answer on StackExchange politics, written by a random person on the internet is likely to be more accurate than the Wikipedia page?  Sure look for a better source.  However "Capital City" may not be a legally defined term.  Eg London is the capital of England, but that is just a general fact, not an official thing.  The list of capitals is normally just a thing of general curiosity, not a thing that needs a high quality source. Exceptional claims require exceptional evidence, the converse of which is that commonplace claims require commonplace evidence

@JamesK What would make me believe it's accurate would be a reference to an official Chinese government source, obviously, because I can go check the source that the random person provided. And this is precisely what the OP asked for. If the districts do not have official "capital cities," that would also be an answer to this question.

@cjs Thanks for the recommendations. I have edited the title of my question and I removed the backstory to clarify the problem I'm solving.

@rdrg109 It may also be worth updating your question to indicate that a) the Wikipedia article you linked has a large notice at the top indicating that it's in need of updating, and b) the article's list of provincial capitals is entirely unreferenced. (Both are obvious if you look at the article, but I have the feeling that close voters aren't bothering to check this, and are simply assuming that every article on Wikipedia is of high quality and has good references.)

Check on the site of Ministry of Natural Resources of the People's Republic of China:
Administrative divisions of China
Sorry, I may not have realized that other countries may not be able to access this website. The following is the administrative division map listed on the website:
China administrative division map

Thanks for the answer. I tried opening the link in Mozilla Firefox 124.0.2, but I got this error: "We can’t connect to the server at www.mnr.gov.cn.". I was able to open this archive version from the 5th of June 2023, and I have read the entire article, but the article doesn't state the capital of any province, so it is not the information that I'm looking for.

The information that I'm looking for is a list of the 23 provinces (in Chinese, 省) along with their capital (in Chinese, 省会) according to the People's Republic of China. The list should list, for example, 广州市 for 广东省 and 长沙市 for 湖南省.

The link seems to be not available from many locations in the world. Would it be possible to upload a screenshot of the current state of the website?

@rdrg109 I have edited the answer, pls check if  it is what you want
